# React Context API no persiste sesión

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, sesiones, graphql

Estoy integrando una aplicación realizada con ReactJS y un login con JWT que al loguearse inserta los datos del usuario y del token en un contexto creado con Context API y hooks.

El contenedor que envuelve al componente padre `App` con el contexto `auth-context.js`:

```js
/**
 * Login
 * @param {string} email 
 * @param {string} password 
 */
async function login(email, password) {
    const client = getClient();
    const CHECK_CREDENTIALS = gql`
        query {
            login(email: "${email}", password: "${password}") {
                userId
                token
                tokenExpiration
            }
        }
    `;
    const { data, loading, errors } = await client.query({
        query: CHECK_CREDENTIALS,
        errorPolicy: 'all'
    });

    if (loading) {
        defaultValue.message = "Validando credenciales";
    }

    if (errors) {
        defaultValue.errors = errors.map(error => <p>{error.message}</p>);
    }

    if (data && data.login) {
        defaultValue.userId = data.login.userId;
        defaultValue.token = data.login.token;
        defaultValue.tokenExpiration = data.login.tokenExpiration;
    }
}
```

Cada componente:

```js
const Dashboard = props => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
  const [notLogged, setNotLogged] = useState(false);
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!context.token) {
      context.errors.push(<p>No autorizado</p>);
      setNotLogged(true);
    }
  }, []);

  function toggleMenu() {
    setOpen(!open)
  }

  return notLogged
  ? <Redirect to="/Login" />
  : (
    <div id="dashboardContainer">
        // contenido
    </div>
  );
}
```

Lo que no tengo claro es, al ir a una URL en el navegador o refrescar la página, los datos del usuario en dicho contexto se borran y hay que hacer login nuevamente.

¿Tienen idea de cómo hacer que estos datos persistan luego de refrescar la página?

Comment: Efectivamente es el comportamiento normal, si refrescas la página pierdes el contexto, puedes utilizar `localStorage` (p.e.) para guardar algun tipo de referencia del usuario que te permita validarlo en cada acceso.

Comment: Como estás utilizando web token, este lo debes guardar como dice @AdolfoOnrubia en el localstorage una vez lo obtienes. Posteriormente lo debes enviar en un header x-auth-app para que lo leas en cada cambio de página y lo valides, en la entrada de tus routers.

Comment: Bueno, @AdolfoOnrubia, escribe un comentario y lo marcaré como el correcto. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posible alternativa a lo que quieres conseguir es, como comentaba:

> *Efectivamente es el comportamiento normal, si refrescas la página
>   pierdes el contexto, puedes utilizar `localStorage` (p.e.) para guardar
>   algún tipo de referencia del usuario que te permita validarlo en cada
>   acceso.*

Si necesitas ayuda sobre el uso de `localStorage` o `sessionStorage` puedes echar un vistazo [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

**En el punto del programa donde tengas autenticado al usuario:**

Suponiendo que la variable `token` contiene el token de usuario y es de tipo `String`.

```
localStorage.setItem('user-token', token);
```

**Mas adelante, en la parte del código donde necesites comprobar si el usuario sigue autenticado:**

```
const userToken = localStorage.getItem('user-token');
```

De esta manera puedes enviar a tu servidor una petición para comprobar si es válido y continuar la sesión.

Me alegra que te haya servido.

Comment: Muchas gracias Adolfo, agradecemos tu edición! :-)

Comment: Muchas gracias Adolfo. Tengo una pregunta: ¿qué pasaría si sabiendo la lógica del token (que aparte se puede desencriptar en la misma página jwt.io) se genera manualmente sin haber hecho autenticación agregando `user-token`? Saludos

Comment: Lo que yo haría sería enviarlo al back y validarlo allí, no sé si es eso lo que preguntas.